# SBT cannot resolve local ivy dependency althought the file is in ivy repo

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management, ivy

I'm having issue with publishing SBT project on Jenkins. For same configuration, it works on my local machine.

I have `core` SBT project (that is published with `publish-local` and then used in another project (`notification service`) as dependency. It worked all fine on Jenkins until few days and nothing changed in any build files but it started to fail, which is really strange.

When we build SBT for core project on Jenkins, it succeeds and all files are present in `~/.ivy2/local/<organisation>/<core-project>_2.12/1.0-SNAPSHOT/`.

But, when notification project builds, it shows

```
==== local: tried
==== public: tried
==== MQTT Repository: tried
==== Releases resolver: tried
==== Snapshots resolver: tried
```

Of course, it should resolve it from first (local). Can you please provide some help. It should not be issue with cache, since it is local dependency. Also, we tried to remove local ivy folder completely, but no luck again. I googled everything on the topic, but no solution :(

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the local is pointing to another location where you have your cache make sure you set the sbt configuration or when you start it pass the parameters

```
-Dsbt.ivy.home=C:\path\cache\ivy2repo
-Dsbt.repository.config=C:\path\sbt\repositories
```

Answer (score 0):

Check local repository name where you published the dependency. Maybe you pulished to `.ivy2/local/default` but sbt looking for it in `.ivy2/local/some_another`